# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysqli

I just switched my webhoster and tried to deploy my PHP application there. Unfortunately it crashes during the login process with this error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/infobo9/www/xxx/login.php on line 41
```

This is the code:

```
$DB = new DB;
$mysqli = $DB->getMySQLiObject();

$sql = "SELECT ios_worker.username, ios_worker.prename, ios_worker.lastname, ios_worker.partnerid_fk, ios_worker.workerid, ios_worker.password, role.rolename, role.roledescription, ios_partners.accessToAdminPortal FROM ios_partners join ios_worker on ios_worker.partnerid_fk = ios_partners.partnerid join workerrole on workerrole.workerid_fk = ios_worker.workerid join role on workerrole.roleid_fk = role.roleid  WHERE ios_worker.username = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$result = $stmt->execute();

var_dump($mysqli);

if (!$result) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}   

var_dump($result);  

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // <-- fails here
   ...
}
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined index: source in /home/infobo9/www/xxx/login.php on line 23
object(mysqli)#2 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["client_info"]=> string(6) "5.5.40" ["client_version"]=> int(50540) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(9) ["host_info"]=> string(33) "xxx via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(10) "5.5.37-log" ["server_version"]=> int(50537) ["stat"]=> string(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "HY000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(82066639) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } 
bool(true) 
    Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/infobo9/www/xxx/login.php on line 41
```

So `$mysqli` is set, and `$result` is `true`. What am I doing wrong?
I also copied the query and it runs without any problems in PHPMyAdmin.

I know this answer was asked multiple times but I am not able to fix this issue since hours and none of the answers fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call fetch on the statement not the $result

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   ...
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

Your `var_dump` of result is an instance of `mysqli` if it was a result set it would be an instance of `mysqli_result`.

The reason you aren't getting results is because you didn't transfer the result set.  In your case `$result` is simply the return value of `$stmt->execute()`, which is a `boolean`.

What you need to do is get the results after you execute the statement.

```
$DB = new DB;
$mysqli = $DB->getMySQLiObject();

$sql = "SELECT ios_worker.username, ios_worker.prename, ios_worker.lastname, ios_worker.partnerid_fk, ios_worker.workerid, ios_worker.password, role.rolename, role.roledescription, ios_partners.accessToAdminPortal FROM ios_partners join ios_worker on ios_worker.partnerid_fk = ios_partners.partnerid join workerrole on workerrole.workerid_fk = ios_worker.workerid join role on workerrole.roleid_fk = role.roleid  WHERE ios_worker.username = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();

//put the results in to the $result variable
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After adding this I get this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in`. I checked if both mysqli and mysqlnd drivers are there and that is the case. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, the extension might not be enabled.  Check your php.ini file and make sure that `extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll` is uncommented.  (Restart your webserver.)  Also, this method is only available in PHP 5.3+.  If you can't use that method then you can still use `bind_result()` in conjunction with `fetch()`

Answer (score 0):

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {...}
if you are getting ERROR : Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() : It requires the mysqlnd driver... if it isn't installed on your webspace you will have to work with BIND_RESULT & FETCH!
link to go through http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php